# JMeter : Maven Build Hangs/Freezes at the end of execution in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am using jmeter-maven-plugin to execute JMeter tests (JMX Files) as a maven project from Jenkins.
What I observed is:
When rampup time is more or virtual user is more, Jenkins freezes the execution towards the end. It keeps on executing for days if not stopped.

When executed outside Jenkins e.g using maven commands directly using cmd, works great. Also when executed directly from JMeter GUI, works fine.

Comment: Deleted as an answer, I wonder if a comment is acceptable...  It sounds like you are suffering from this bug: https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/108

It's fixed in 1.10.1.

The workaround in earlier versions is to set the configuration option:

<suppressJMeterOutput>false</suppressJMeterOutput>

Comment: The solution to this issue : https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/116
Solution was by me only which I liked to your mentioned issue as both are related. :)

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

There was an [issue](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/116) with jmeter maven plugin which was fixed in later version.

Solution was made by Abhishek Swain.

See